Suma de inputs dinámicos y estaticos
Quisiera pedirles ayuda con los siguiente, tengo un formulario el cual genera inputs dinámicamente, según el contenido de una base de datos.
Esto trata de que un conjunto de personas viaja y pueden quedarse en distintas áreas de la ciudad (central, periferia y rural). Cada persona se puede quedar unos días en una, dos o las tres áreas. Cada área tiene un costo especifico entonces de acuerdo al área y la cantidad de días que se queda se hace un calculo y sale un monto total por persona.
Además, previamente un responsable registra el viaje, el lugar destino (área central, periferia o rural) y las fechas de inicio y final del viaje, entonces hago una resta de las fechas y lleno la casilla correspondiente con el número de días, pero en el registro el encargado puede dejar esa cantidad o distribuir la cantidad de días en las otras casillas.
El objetivo es sumar la cantidad de días y costo por persona, por favor podrían ayudarme con eso
 
 <?php
$importecentro = $centro[0]['importe'];
$importeperiferia = $periferia[0]['importe'];
$importeRural = $rural[0]['importe'];

$diascentro = 0;
$diasperiferia = 0;
$diasrural = 0;
$nroDias = 0;


if ($catmunicipio == 'CENTRO') {
    $diascentro = $dias;
} elseif ($catmunicipio == 'PERIFERIA') {
    $diasperiferia = $dias;
} elseif ($catmunicipio == 'RURAL') {
    $diasrural = $dias;
}
  
 
 <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<?php
    foreach ($personas as $row) {
?>
<div class="grid-content4">
    
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="<?php echo 'nombre' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'nombre' . $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo mb_strtoupper($row['nombre'], 'UTF-8'); ?>" readonly>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="<?php echo 'lugar_centro' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'lugar_centro' . $row['id']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div>
         <input class="form-control"type="text" id="<?php echo 'dias_centro' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'dias_centro' . $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $diascentro; ?>">
     </div>
    <div>
        <input class=" form-control" type="text" id="<?php echo 'lugar_periferia' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'lugar_periferia' . $row['id']; ?>">
     </div>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type=" text" id="<?php echo 'dias_periferia' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'dias_periferia' . $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $diasperiferia; ?>">
     </div>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="<?php echo 'lugar_rural' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'lugar_rural' . $row['id']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type=" text" id="<?php echo 'dias_rural' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'dias_rural' . $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $diasrural; ?>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" type=" text" id="<?php echo 'totaldias' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'totaldias' . $row['id']; ?>">
     </div>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control costo" style="width:80px;" type=" text" id="<?php echo 'costo' . $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo 'costo' . $row['id']; ?>">
    </div>
</div>
     <?php
        }
     ?>
    <div class="grid-content3">
        <div>TOTAL</div>
        <div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" disabled></div>
    </div>


¿Cómo es y dónde cumplimentas ese array $personas? Como entiendo que salga de una bases de datos, yo te recomendaría montar todo esto en el modelo y construir tu formulario como una vista o visualización en HTML del resultado de una consulta a tu base de datos que tendrá varias tablas en donde almacenarás lo necesario para realizar todos esos cálculos

$personas se carga con una consulta a la base de datos, todo esto se hace en el controlador

$personas = new PersonasModel();
$data['personas'] = $ personas->listadoPersonas($id_actividad);

MODELO
public function listadoPersonas($id){
        return $this->select('*')
        ->find($id);
    }```                                                                                                       
$id_actividad es el id que se obtiene cuando se registra la actividad, en un paso previo.

Genial, pues modifica la pregunta y añade este fragmento de código. Después, intenta hacer una consulta a la base de datos (añadiendo las tablas y campos que necesites) con la que obtener todos los datos para el formulario y, si no te sale, añades también ese intento y te ayudamos. Ya casi lo tienes.
